# Longitudinal mediation model but one variable per time point

Tags: panel-data, mediation

I have recently encountered a paper where authors ran a longitudinal mediation model where the predictor (only measured at Time 1), mediator (only measured at Time 2), and outcome (only measured at Time 3) variables were only measured once. This was a correlational research (not experimental). Can anyone tell me what the advantage/disadvantage of this design in general and also compared to a regular cross-sectional mediation model where all variables are measured at a single time point? I tried to educate myself by searching other examples, but I was not able to find any.
Thank you!